# Main Camera Referenced script is missing

Tags: mrtk

I know, there is always a lot of questions about this error BUT I didn't succeed to fix it with the previous answers...

So, please, let me explain.

I'm working with the Hololens tech. Recently, I have updated from HoloToolKit to MRTK V2 (new SDK provided by Microsoft and the community). My app worked with HoloToolKit, Unity and 2017.4. I updated for MRTKv2 and 2019.2 (recommended).

I have some scripts that use the camera position. In my previous app, Camera was BiCamera (GameObject), child of Basic (GameObject). And my BiCamera was tagged as MainCamera. Right now, my camera was Main Camera (with a space between the 2 words), tagged MainCamera, child of MixedRealityPlayspace. This camera is provided by the MRTKv2. I can't change the settings.

So, when I'm in a Play mode I have this message in yellow :

```
 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is missing!
```

And when I move my Main Camera in order to simulate a walk of the user (Hololens = augmented reality), I have this message in red :

```
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 TextSpeedUI.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/TextSpeedUI.cs:23)
```

I think the second message is linked to the first... My script TextSpeedUI needs the camera.transform to calculate walking speed (in fact not directly, he finds the public variable from another GameObject, but this GameObject requires Camera.transform).

An other option is linked with the GameObject Main Camera provided by MRTK because when I select this GameObject I have a missing script. A message says that I have to fix compile errors... But perhaps it's a consequence not the origin... I'm lost.

TextSpeedUI.cs 23

```
 if (sd.isActiveAndEnabled && sd.Steps.Count > 4)
 {
     xzSpeed = (sd.Steps[sd.Steps.Count - 1].localMinPosition - sd.Steps[sd.Steps.Count - 4].localMinPosition) / ((sd.Steps[sd.Steps.Count - 1].t - sd.Steps[sd.Steps.Count - 4].t));
     txt.text = (xzSpeed.magnitude * 3.6).ToString("0.##"); // speed in km/h
 }
```

sd comes from public StepDetector sd; which is at the beginning of my script TextSpeedUI.cs

And my script StepDetector.cs calls public DataManager dm;

In my DataManager.cs script, I call at the beginning :

```
 public Camera Cam { get; private set; }
```

And in void Start :

```
 Cam = Camera.main;
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by myself (just remove the component). It seems that it doesn't have consequence on my scene...